# Why does C# bind the local variables up-front?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

So in C#, you might have the following code:

```
void DoSomething()
{
    //some code.
    int x = 5;
    //some more code.
}
```

As soon as you enter DoSomething, the CLR sets up space for int x.  Why does it not wait until it reaches the line with int x =5 on it?  Especially since even though x is bound, it doesn't let you actually use it until that line is reached anyway?

Comment: Why would adjusting the stack size incrementally be any better than reserving it all up front?

Comment: presumably, it takes some time to mess with the stack...  if I have a lot of local variables, why wait on them when I don't have to (yet)?

Comment: Right, it does take some time to mess with the stack, so doing it all up front instead of over and over every time a new variable enters scope is exactly what's done.

Comment: In Delphi and Pascal, a developer had to define variables for the method up front. Anders Hejlsberg, participated in creation of both Delphi and C#, so I assume he was behind this behavior. Other then that, I guess it is for performance sake, giving an execution environment an idea, of how much maximum memory will get allocated during an execution of this block of code.

Comment: would you start to pass the wooden old bridge, eventhough you'd know that there'll be no way to pass with all the fat boys coming across the way?

Comment: This is a bit of speculative question. Short of @EricLippert, I'm not sure who could answer it definitively...

Comment: @BeytanKurt I'm not sure I understand your analogy.

Comment: @GWLlosa I mean, if there's a possibility to overhead your available memory, is it sake to run the function at the beginning?

Comment: @GWLlosa, good question, but SO is not the correct place to discuss. I voted to close

Comment: Given I never wrote a virtual machine myself, i can't prove anything, but since you know all variables you will need in a method beforehand in a compiled language, allocating the full stack to hold them all at the beginning gets them all to be contiguous in memory and much more likely that they will be in the processor cache when needed. Also, this is not a CLR thing, the JVM does the same.

Comment: @L.B Its a specific question which presumably has a specific answer...  why is it not SO appropriate?

Comment: @ildjarn Isn't it also possible that I won't necessarily need all the variables, and therefore allocating them all is wasteful?

Comment: @GWLlosa if optimizations are enabled, unused variables will not be allocated.

Comment: @GWLlosa : No, stack reservation is typically just a register value change (`esp` on x86) -- no "allocation" is done until a `new` is encountered, all that's being done here is reserving stack space.

Comment: @GWLlosa, keyword is *presumably*

Comment: @GWLlosa - From the FAQ: `You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.`. Do you have a specific scenario where this is causing you problems?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> As soon as you enter `DoSomething`, the CLR sets up space for `int x`. Why does it not wait until it reaches the line with `int x = 5` on it?

The question is not answerable because the entire question is founded on an incorrect premise. The storage space for the local variable may be:

- allocated when the method is first entered
- allocated when control reaches the declaration
- allocated when control reaches the initialization (assuming initialization and declaration are different)
- allocated under special circumstances -- if for example the local is a closed-over local of a lambda, or in an iterator block, or in an async block, how and when the local storage is allocated can get complicated
- elided entirely; if the local is never used then it might not be allocated in the first place.

The C# compiler and the jit compiler definitely ensure that the local storage is allocated in a way that is **correct**, and attempt to ensure that it is **efficient**. How they choose to do so depends on the exact situation. It might be more efficient to allocate the space up front, and it might be more efficient to allocate it for only as long as the variable is in use; the jitter is permitted broad lattitude in choosing the lifetime of a local variable. Local variables are permitted to live both longer and shorter than their scopes would imply if the jitter can do so without violating program correctness.

Since the premise of the question is incorrect, there is no answer to the question. Ask a better question.

Comment: The answer is [mu](http://bit.ly/s4jx85).

Comment: 10 upvotes and an accept for an answer that claims there is no answer to question. This answer appears to contradict itself by existing.

Comment: @IgbyLargeman: The hint you get when you hover over the upvote is "this answer is useful", not "this answer answers the question that was asked". If pointing out that a question is predicated on an incorrect premise is *useful* then there is no contradiction there.

Comment: I still think you've contributed to the instability of the fabric of spacetime, if only a little. Don't blame me when a Chesterfield sofa materializes in your office, that's all I'm saying.

Comment: @IgbyLargeman: I already have a Chesterfield in my office, actually. (And I note that you have outed yourself as probably being (like me) an English speaking Canadian; very few people in the world call sofas "Chesterfields" outside of English Canada.)

Comment: I had a feeling you might say that. I bet your office is sweet. I'm an English speaking Australian (but living one state south of you), but the Chesterfield reference comes to me from Douglas Adams. In Australia we just call it a couch.

Answer (score 10):

As you might know, there are several steps from C# code to the native code those are:

- Compiling from C# to IL(bytecode)
- JITting from bytecode to native code

C# does not have any control of the time when memory is allocated, what you call *binding*, this is entirely up to JIT. Getting this out of the way let's see what *is* in C#'s control. The byte code produced by C# has to adhere [CLR ECMA](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-335.pdf) standard. If we go to section 12.1.6.1 of Partition 1 we will see, that the standard defines that the local variable's home is *in the method header*. Since method signatures as a rule tend to show up in the beginning of a method in a listing, you get a (false) impression that they are *bound* upfront, which in fact may or may not be the case.

If you are however looking at the compiled native code, the result may vary from platform to platform. Historically allocating space on CPU stack for a local variable is done by a single CPU instruction of changing stack pointer. If you want to do it variable by variable then you will have *many* instructions, one per variable, which is less efficient. This is why, at least on x86 you are going to see that the space on CPU stack is allocated upfront.

Answer (score 3):

What should the compiler do if it finds something similar to:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
 {
     int j = .... //should the compiler set up space when it reaches this line? 1000 times?
 }
```

Besides I really think the cost of setting up space of locals is not a factor. If it gets to be then you are probably dealing with way too many locals in one single method and you are better off refactoring your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to based on a few assumptions:

- The cost of setup is always going to be high
- Setup is only going to happen a small number of times
- The reference / value type at the CLR level always has a one to  one mapping with the variable at the C# level

These may be true for your code but may not hold true for the majority of code out there.

The assumptions also seem to ignore the presence of underlying layers of the process that compile / interpret this down to machine code.

In short, the code you write in C# is an abstraction which relies upon IL which is another abstraction which relies upon the CLR which is another abstraction and so on.

For what it's worth, I have serious doubts about this decision ever having a significant impact on your application's performance ... but maybe the like of Eric Lippert ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/ ) can share a more in-depth analysis.